# How to parse JSON in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

i have this json string

```
{
    "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/",
    "city": [
        {
            "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/ABJ/",
            "agencyCollection": {
                "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/ABJ/agencyCollection/"
            },
            "codecit": "ABJ",
            "country": {
                "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/ABJ/country/"
            },
            "namecit": "ABIDJAN"
        },
        {
            "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/ALG/",
            "agencyCollection": {
                "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/ALG/agencyCollection/",
                "agency": [
                    {
                        "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/ALG/agencyCollection/3/"
                    },
                    {
                        "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/ALG/agencyCollection/4/"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "codecit": "ALG",
            "country": {
                "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/ALG/country/"
            },
            "namecit": "ALGER"
        },
        {
            "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/AMS/",
            "agencyCollection": {
                "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/AMS/agencyCollection/",
                "agency": [
                    {
                        "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/AMS/agencyCollection/5/"
                    },
                    {
                        "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/AMS/agencyCollection/6/"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "codecit": "AMS",
            "country": {
                "@uri": "http://localhost:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/AMS/country/"
            },
            "namecit": "AMSTERDAM"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to parse it, I wrote this code

```
NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:responseString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];   
NSDictionary *json    = [myJSON JSONValue];
//NSLog(responseString);
NSArray *citysList    =  [json objectForKey:@"city"];
NSLog(@"ok");
NSLog(@" number of element : %@", [citysList count]);
```

But I have 0 number of element , help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael is right. Here's a more detailed answer:

`initWithContentsOfFile` takes a string containing a file path (e.g. "/users/mehdi/documents/myFile.txt"). You seem to be passing in your actual JSON string, which isn't a file path. As a result, `initWithContentsOfFile` is probably returning `nil`.

Check this by asking:

```
if (myJSON == nil) NSLog(@"myJSON variable == nil!");
```

If it is nil, then your code is also setting `json` and `citysList` to nil.

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *json    = [responseString JSONValue];
NSArray *citysList    =  [json objectForKey:@"city"];
NSLog(@" number of element : %d", [citysList count]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an initWithContentsOfFile but passing in a string. Have you tried simply [responseString JSONValue]? Your code suggests that responseString has the PATH to the file you're trying to open, not your full response string itself.